# repeat question after answer is wrong, including a "skip" option

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner with python and I wrote a quiz program, how do I repeat a question in my quiz if the answer given is wrong? I'd also like to give the user an option to skip to the next question in the same text box as the answer.

This is my current source code:

```
score = 0
q1 = input("What is the square root of 64?: ")
if q1 == ("8"):
    print("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
if q1 == ("skip"):
    break
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
print("")
q2 = input("Who was president during the year 1970?: ")
if q2 == ("Richard Nixon") or q2 == ("richard nixon"):
    print("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
print("")
q3 = input("How many stars are on the American flag?: ")
if q3 == ("50"):
    print("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
print("")
q4 = input("In the US, which state has the largest population?: ")
if q4 == ("California") or q4 == ("california"):
    print("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
print("")
q5 = input("Who discovered the Americas in 1492?: ")
if q5 == ("Christopher Columbus") or q5 == ("christopher columbus"):
    print("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
print("")

if score == 0:
    print("Your score is 0. Better luck next time.")
if score == 1:
    print("Your score is 1. Better luck next time.")
if score == 2:
    print("Your score is 2. Better luck next time.")
if score == 3:
    print("Your score is 3. Not bad. Try again soon!")
if score == 4:
    print("Your score is 4. Not bad. Try again soon!")
if score == 5:
    print("Your score is 5. Awesome! You rock!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make use of functions to call the same code to show the question.

To do the skipping, you can have the program detect a special answer (in the example below it's "skip") and use that to recognize when to skip to the next question).

Here's an example:

```
QUESTIONS = {'question1' : 'answer', 'question2': 'answer'}
score = 0

def ask_question(question, answer):
  global score
  while True:
    response = input(question + "\n")
    if response == 'skip':
      return
    elif response == answer:
      score += 1
      break

def question_loop():
  for question, answer in QUESTIONS.items():
    ask_question(question, answer)

def print_results():
  #print results here
  pass

question_loop()
print_results()
```